# Template doesn't render into named outlet

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create several pages that will use the same menu so that I can save the state of the menu easily and avoid code duplication. My problem is that the menu template doesn't render in the menu outlet of the pages.

Here is the code :

```
App.Router.map(function() {
     // put your routes here
     this.resource('profil', function() {
     this.route('news');
     this.route('menu');
  });
});

App.MenuRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
renderTemplate: function() {
     this.render({
        into: 'profil/news',
        outlet: 'menu',
     });
    }
 });
```

And in index.html I have  :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="profil/news">
     ...
     {{outlet}}
     {{outlet menu}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="menu">
    ...
</script>
```

The template 'profil/news' is rendered but the template 'menu' is not rendered at all : it should be rendered inside 'profil/news' when I visit profil/news . Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to use :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="profil/news">
   ...
   {{outlet}}
   {{render 'profil/menu'}}
</script>
```

And to change the name of the handlebar to match the routing:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="profil/menu">
```

Moreover, the statement beginning with App.Menuroute is unnecessary and be removed.

Now everything is working as expected.